# In Chrome extension determine if the user clicked the browser's Back or Forward button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I know whether the user clicked back/forward button in Chrome from within my Chrome Extension?

The only API that could give me any such info is the [`chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCommitted) which in the case of when the back or forward button are clicked, sends a `NavigationQualifier` containing the string `'forward_back'`. The problem here is that I'm not able to distinguish between the two buttons.

Comment: You want to capture every back/forward navigation?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to be notified every time the user clicks on the back/forward buttons.

Comment: we faced the same issue. have you found a way to listen to the clicking Back/Forward button?

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to be a straight forward way :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `tabs` API's `onUpdated` event if that's good enough for you.

Alternatively, you could use the HTML5 history API and register a `window.onpopstate` handler. Do that from within a content script that runs before the page.

Comment: What do you mean by the tab's 'onChanged' event ? I can find no such event. If you mean the 'onUpdated', it doesn't have sufficient information to tell whether the user clicked the 'back' or 'forward' buttons. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are correct, I wasn't clear (from your comment on the original question) whether that was a requirement or not, that's why I wrote "if that's good enough for you". My other idea, about using `window.onpopstate`, still stands. Does that answer the requirement?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The `window.onpopstate` event is only triggered when the user navigates between two history entries for the same document. I'm trying to listen to every click on 'back' and 'forward' at the browser level not for a specific document.

Comment: Re-read my suggestion: have your content script injected into *every* document. Your content script will register for the `popstate` event. You can do whatever you want there. If another document gets loaded as a result, your content script is again run in the content of that document, again registers for `popstate`, etc.

Comment: I fail to understand how this satisfies my need. Can you give me an example which prints to the console "the back button was pressed" or alternatively "the forward button was pressed".